# R ggplot2 annotate with subscript and tilde

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript, annotate, tilde

I'm trying to annotate a ggplot2 plot with a label that states the distribution for X1 ~ N(mu=10,sigma=3), where the 1 is meant to be subscript, like this:

```
label1<-"X[1] ~ N( \U03bc = 10, \U03c3 = 3)"
```

When I use label1 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
label1<-"X[1] ~ N( \U03bc = 10, \U03c3 = 3)"
ggplot() + annotate("text", x=18,y=0.05,label=label1)
```

The subscript is ignored, the rest is what is wanted.

When I use label1 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
label1<-"X[1] ~ N( \U03bc = 10, \U03c3 = 3)"
ggplot() + annotate("text", x=18,y=0.05,label=label1,parse=TRUE)
```

the subscript is plotted correct, but the tilde transforms in a space.

Any advice how to make and the subscript and the tilde-sign happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can replace `~` with `%~%` in method 2 (i.e. `parse = TRUE`). I also replaced the unicode for mu & sigma with their greek letter representations:

```
label1 <- "X[1] %~% N(mu == 10, sigma == 3)"
ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x=18, y=0.05, label=label1, parse=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `%` to the tilde as such:

```
label1<-"X[1] %~% N( \U03bc = 10, \U03c3 = 3)"
```

Comment: for more details see: http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/

Comment: In a title e.g. ``labs(title = parse(text = "X[1] %~% N( \U03bc = 10, \U03c3 = 3)"))``